# create thumbnails with WWW::Mechanize::FireFox using Mozrepl - some debug attempts

Tags: perl, parsing, firefox-addon, mechanize, mozrepl

well i run this script , which is written to do some screenshots of websites 
i have also up and running mozrepl

here we have the file with some of the requested urls ... note this is only a short snippet of the real list - the real list is much much longer. it contains more than 3500 lines and URLs

```
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
http://www.zug.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
http://www.phvs.ch
http://www.phtg.ch
http://www.phsg.ch
http://www.phsh.ch
http://www.phr.ch
http://www.hepfr.ch/
http://www.phbern.ch
http://www.ph-solothurn.ch
http://www.pfh-gr.ch
http://www.ma-shp.luzern.phz.ch
http://www.heilpaedagogik.phbern.ch/
```

whats strange is the output - see below... 
question: should i do change the script

why do i ge the output with the following little script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open(INPUT, "<urls.txt") or die $!;

while (<INPUT>) {
        chomp;
        print "$_\n";
        $mech->get($_);
        my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        my $name = "$_";
        $name =~s/^www\.//;
        $name .= ".png";
        open(OUTPUT, ">$name");
        print OUTPUT $png;
        sleep (5);
}
```

see here the well overwhelming output - to be frank i never have thught to get such a funny output .. i have to debug the whole code.... see below,

```
http://www.unifr.ch/sfm
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 2.
http://www.zug.phz.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 3.
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 4.
http://www.luzern.phz.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 5.
http://www.schwyz.phz.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 6.
http://www.phvs.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 7.
http://www.phtg.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 8.
http://www.phsg.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 9.
http://www.phsh.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 10.
http://www.phr.ch
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 11.
http://www.hepfr.ch/
print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT at test_3.pl line 20, <INPUT> line 12.
http://www.phbern.ch
```

Some musings: well -firstly, i think this is not a very serious error - i think i have to debug it and then it will  work better.
Second, i firstly thought that the script seemed "to overload the machine"? 
Now i am not very sure about that: the symptoms do look strange but i guess that it is not neecessary to conclude an "overloading of the machine"

Third,  well i think of certain steps that have to be taken to ensure that the problem is at all related to WWW::Mechanize::Firefox at all? 
This leads me to the point to what Perl warning means and to the idea to use the diagnostics pragma to get more explanation: what do you think?

```
print() on unopened filehandle FH at -e line 1 (#2) (W unopened) An I/O operation was attempted on a filehandle that w +as never initialized.
```

**firstly** - we need to do an open(), a sysopen(), or a so +cket() call, or call a constructor from the FileHandle package
besides that - alternatively, print() on closed filehandle OUTPUT also gives lots of answers that will tell us that we did not use autodie and also did not check the return value of open.
Above all i have to debug it and make sure to find where the error comes into play[/QUOTE]

But after some musings i think that it is worth to have a closer look at all test things-,
what do you think about the idea *always* test to make sure the file is open before using it.That means that we should also get in the habit of using the three

```
arg open():

open my $fh, '>', $name or die "Can't open file $name : $!";
print $fh $stuff;
```

well - i guess that we can or should work around this without using `die()`,
but we d have to manually have some method to let us know which files couldn't be created. In our case, it looks **like all of them**....that are shown above...

**update** in choosing a good file name you mean that i need to have a file name to store the images.. Note: i want to **store all of them locally**. But if i have a huge list of urls then i get a huge list of **output files**.  Therefore i need to have good file names. Can we **reflect those things** and needs in the programme!?

the **very latest update**; there seem to be some **errors with mechanize**.... i guess so!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you would like to print out binary data (jpg file), you have to set it explicitly.
Second, close a filehandler if you does not need it anymore and you 'or die' on open.
Third choose a good file name.

Regards,

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = new WWW::Mechanize::Firefox();

open(INPUT, "<urls.txt") or die $!;

while (<INPUT>) {
        chomp;
        next if $_ =~ m/http/i;
        print "$_\n";
        $mech->get($_);
        my $png = $mech->content_as_png();
        my $name = "$_";
        $name =~s#http://##is;
        $name =~s#/##gis;$name =~s#\s+\z##is;$name =~s#\A\s+##is;
        $name =~s/^www\.//;
        $name .= ".png";
        open(my $out, ">",$name) or die $!;
        binmode($out);
        print $out $png;
        close($out);
        sleep (5);
}
```

Comment: Hello dear user1126070 - thx alot. I will do as adviced. i will set it explicitly and close a filehandler if i do not need it anymore and you 'or die' on open. By choosing a good file name you mean that i need to have a file name to store the images.. Note: i want to **store all of them locally**. But if i have a huge list of urls then i get a huge list of **output files**.  Therefore i need to have good file names. Can we **reflect those things** and needs in the programme!?

look forward to hear . thx alot in advance

Comment: 'Good filename', I mean, to sanitize them. Remove '://,/', and other things that may prevent them to be created. I added some regexps to do this.

Comment: hello user1126070 thx alot for the additional hints. you deserve a monster congrats. Greetings

Comment: update; there seem to be some errors with mechanize.... i guess so!!!

what do you say!!??